# visual studio 2019 error : access denied , but I don't know what is the reason for it

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

I want to run Physx in Visual Studio 2019 but when I start debugging, it says access denied cause it cant start
"PhysX-4.1\physx\compiler\vc16win64\x64\debug\ALL_BUILD". I solved typeinfo.h problem, directX SDK problem, but I couldn't solve it though I searched a lot for it. I need you guys help....
*it is not about computer vaccine program or administration for VS 2019. I already tried it.

Comment: ***it cant start "PhysX-4.1\physx\compiler\vc16win64\x64\debug\ALL_BUILD*** Is a user error. ALL_BUILD is not an executable program. Its a target that forces all other dependent targets (projects in Visual Studio) to build. Select an executable target if you are going to debug.

Comment: If you right click on an executable project in Visual Studio there will be an option to "Set as startup project" select that then when you debug it will debug the executable instead of "ALL_BUILD"